# How would I click this element in pupeteer?

Tags: javascript, html, puppeteer

```
<button
  data-test="register-link"
  class="variant-action line-height-150pct text-size-default spacing-primary weight-semibold align-left square svelte-1aq1zn0"
>
  <span class="content-or-loader svelte-1uofbko">Register</span>
</button>
```

I have tried using $x for xpath, i've tried evuating it, i've tried getting it by the "data" tag (data-test) and nothing is working to click this, it either returns an empty array or it says click is not a function.

site: stake.com register button

Comment: Please share your code as a [mcve]. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

please use the below snippet

```
await page.$eval('button[data-test="register-link"]',registerButton=>registerButton.click())
```